# How can I copy text to the clipboard using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, clipboard

I would like to create an application using AppleScript to copy the system info and email it to myself.  I know to to do the emailing aspect and how to make the email have the content of whatever is in the clipboard.  How might I use AppleScript coding to copy text to the clipboard?

In case it helps here is the way to email whatever is in the clipboard:

```
set a to "uselessdecoy@gmail.com"
tell application "Mail"
tell (make new outgoing message)
set subject to (the clipboard)
set content to "content"
make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:a}
send
end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You simply use

```
set the clipboard to "Some text"
```

You can also assign to the various parts of the clipboard (plain text, unicode, pict) directly, as in:

```
set the clipboard to {text:(outputText as string), Unicode text:outputText}
```

Comment: Is it possible to copy a binary file (i.e. mp4) from a given path to clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

JXA Example - Copying Safari URL and Title into Clipboard.

```js
var appSafari = Application("com.apple.Safari");
appSafari.includeStandardAdditions = true


var winFront = appSafari.windows[0];
var winFrontName = winFront.name().split("\"").join("'");
var currentTabURL = winFront.currentTab().url();
var result = `${winFrontName}: ${currentTabURL}`;

appSafari.setTheClipboardTo(result)
```